# Put file in sub folder to google drive use laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have problems in my code to upload files to google drive when i using package `nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive`, this code will be created text.txt to subdirectory = "Contract", but I have many folders with different names and they are the same 2 folders Children are: Contract, Project. I can't find a way to create `text.txt` into the folder name I want

I'm tried to fix query in

```
$dir = $contents->where('type', '=', 'dir')
    ->where('filename', '=', 'Contract')
    ->first();
```

but it not work.

```
    Route::get('put-in-dir', function() {
$dir = '/';
$recursive = true; // Get subdirectories also?
$contents = collect(Storage::cloud()->listContents($dir, $recursive));

$dir = $contents->where('type', '=', 'dir')
    ->where('filename', '=', 'Contract')
    ->first(); // There could be duplicate directory names!

if ( ! $dir) {
    return 'Directory does not exist!';
}

Storage::cloud()->put($dir['path'].'/test.txt', 'Hello World');

return 'File was created in the sub directory in Google Drive';
});
```

i want to create text.txt into forder i want. examp: i want to create in Contract of Yasuo..

```
Shaco-
  --Contract
  --Project
Yasuo-
  --Contract
  --Project
```

Answer (score -1):

i found solution. this is my solution:

```
Route::get('put-in-dir', function() {
$content = collect(Storage::cloud()->listContents('/', false));
    foreach ($content as $key => $value) {
        if($value['name'] == 'MrTrung')
            $root = $value['path'];
    }
    //dd($root);
$dir = '/'.$root;
$recursive = true; // Get subdirectories also?
$contents = collect(Storage::cloud()->listContents($dir, $recursive));

$dir = $contents->where('type', '=', 'dir')
    ->where('filename', '=', 'Contract')
    ->first(); // There could be duplicate directory names!
if ( ! $dir) {
    return 'Directory does not exist!';
}
Storage::cloud()->put($dir['path'].'/test.txt', 'Hello World');
return 'File was created in the sub directory in Google Drive';
});
```

note: evething is right when you install google drive API v3. And I follow this way: https://gist.github.com/ivanvermeyen/cc7c59c185daad9d4e7cb8c661d7b89b

good luck.